# get and set methods for Arraylists in Java

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, get, set

I was wondering can you make an Arraylist Method? And if so how do you create get and set methods for an Arraylist.

For example I want to create an Array list to hold the five different objects that I set like this in the main method:

```
Random thing = new Random();
thing1.setName("Allen");
thing1.setheight(89);
```

etc.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: An arraylist already has get set, and add methods.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking post more code or something.

Comment: Do you mean you want to create an `ArrayList<Random>`?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking here.  But usually, with questions of the "can you do this" variety, the best thing to do is to try it out and see what happens, maybe with occasional reference to the Javadocs for whatever classes you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You could technically do this:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.add("Name");
list.add(89);
```

However this is not great because you would need to know ahead of time which item in the ArrayList is of what type in case you want to perform specific operations on certain items. A better solution would be to create a Person object i.e.

```
class Person{
     //fields
     //setter getter methods
}
```

and then do something like this:

```
ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
Person p = new Person();
p.setName("Name");
list.add(p);
```

In this case Person would be the equivalent of your Random object.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not clear but if you want to hold any type of data you can define `ArrayList<Object>`

**EDIT**

or 
ArrayList
Without specifying generic type. the default is Object